# error signing in to github with github pull requests and issues/GHPRI in vscode

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

on Github sidebar, it asks me to sign in

[github sign in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhDho.png)

after click, it pops error message. I cannot create issues.(My internet connection is ok. I can push to github.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqPpH.png)

There is also a situation that pull requests and issues keeps loading, TODO does not pop out create issue icon

[loading does not load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBt8B.png)

Please help

Comment: It would help to limit the question to a single problem and evaluate more upon it. It there a problem with logging in, or with using the extension to create issues?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.